# Ubuntu 12.04 randomly freezes

Tags: 12.04, graphics, freeze

#### Hello. I use Ubuntu 12.04 with wubi.

> The problem is that ubuntu randomly freezes when i move the mouse cursor. The system doesent have to restart i just have to press (ctrl+alt+f1) and then (ctrl+alt+f7) this works and i can use ubuntu a bit more but then it freezes again. I am using Asus k53sm laptop with 4gb ram, intel i5 processor and nvidia gt 630m. Is there a way to fix this problem?

*Im sorry if this is a duplicate, i dident find a ubuntu freeze problem like this.*

Comment: What kind of freeze? Does music stop etc., or is it just the mouse that dies?

Comment: When i watch youtube the screen freezes butthe sound continues and its the same with movies and music.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the proprietary nvidia driver and see if that helps. It may be related to the nvidia video drivers.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

Comment: I am going totest if this works. According to the driver installer or what it is called i alredy have the latest drives but it is worth a try.

Comment: Nope dident work, it dident find any newer updates. thx anyway

Comment: Okej i think this worked after all. I restarted the computer and then ubuntu found some new firmware. So far ubuntu has not frozen, its a record =D i will see if it freezes later but it looks like it works thx =D

Comment: Nope it is starting to freeze again. I think it has something to do with the graphics though because the screen loads like big black pixels untill the desktop is loaded.

Comment: you can try installing the linux drivers from nvidia's support page and installing them with their linux installer. Since it's no through ubuntu's package manager, it may break when you're updating your system, so there's a chance that you will have to install it again in the future, but it has worked for me in the past.

When installing, you have to close your X server with:

    sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop

or, if youre running Unity:

    sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop

Then you will have to unzip the installer file and run it with:

    sudo sh ./NVIDIA-xxxxxx.run

Comment: Ok i will try and see if i can get it to work

Comment: I weren't successfull with the nvidia driver installation because somehow nvidias "driver center" didnt find drivers for my graphics card. I will see if the problem continues if it dosent i will set this as the sulution and if it do continue i will see if someone might have a solution. Thxs for all the help anyway.